# User_ID on Fan Page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access the users_id for the current user on one of my tabs.

I have tried the majority of the methods in the posts on here but to no avail...

I know I can find the param in here

```
print_r(parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],APP_SECRET)) ;
```

But I need to do some auth on the fan page. Does anyone know how to bring up the auth dialog in a popup using the PHP SDK?

For reference, its being done on this page. http://www.facebook.com/willitblend?sk=app_107727025983833

Thanks

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP SDK only provides a method to get the login link for a user, redirecting them to another page where the Auth Dialog appears.

I usually do it with the help of the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), which has a method for checking if the user is logged in, and showing the popup if they aren't.
Check [FB.getLoginStatus()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and [FB.login()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: Great that FB.login() seems to really help, although the experience isnt great. It opens the dialog in popup window rather than a lightbox style... It then leaves me with a blank screen too when clicking to authorise.

Comment: I have now redirected away with the auth then redirected back to the page. Seems to work well. Thanks for your help :)